# Opening a browser window after a visual studio-created setup file finishes installing

Tags: c#, setup-project, bho

I'm making a setup file (.msi) using a visual studio setup project. Currently, I need to register a component -a BHO- along with the main installation and open a browser window to a site that requires this component in order to work as intended.

So far, I've managed to install the component by registering it with the "vsdrfCOM" option on the component file properties.

As for opening the browser window, I created an installation class which overrides the OnAfterInstall method and creates a browser window, opening it on said site. Then I added this class on my project as an "Install" custom action. Below is the code I'm using.

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url);
```

The problem I'm having is that right after the progression bar form, the browser window opened by the setup file doesn't load the BHO. Yet, if I execute IExplorer.exe from anywhere else, even before the browser window shows up via setup, it identifies the BHO just fine. Any ideas of why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Override the [Commit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.commit.aspx) method.

Comment: Ack, it didn't work; I overloaded the method and rebuilt: nothing happened after installation. 

I tried calling the installation class as a "Commit" custom action, it did the same as the first situation: called the browser before the "Close" user-click on the last form.

Comment: it may be your BHO is not enabled. so first enable your BHO. than it will work

Answer (score 0):

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost/[your_site]/Default.aspx");

But I don't know how to get [your_site] in Installer.Commit Method.